# Using AVG when Order By is Necessary

Tags: sql

I'm trying to average the results of 4 columns of the past 3 completed drives. If I do not order by FromDateTime desc, I get the earliest drives for the account. Which is not what I need.

But when I try to pull the Average for the 4 columns, I'm getting this message:
Column "rpt_DriveMaster.FromDateTime" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone help me understand how to properly write this query?  Should I be looking at a sub-query? Just not sure.

```
SELECT top 3 
AVG(ProcedureProjection),
AVG(ProceduresPerformed),
AVG(DPaCT.ProductProjection),
AVG(DPaCT.ProductsCollected)
/*DM.DriveID, DM.FromDateTime, DM.AccountID, Acct.Name, DPaCT.ProcedureProjection, 
DPaCT.ProductProjection, DPaCT.ProceduresPerformed, DPaCT.ProductsCollected*/
FROM rpt_DriveMaster DM 
INNER JOIN DriveProjectionandCollectedTotals DPaCT ON DM.DriveID = DPaCT.DriveID 
INNER JOIN rpt_Accounts Acct ON DM.AccountID = Acct.AccountID
where Acct.accountid='17845' and DM.fromdatetime < '2014-04-01' and DM.StatusID='2'
Order by DM.FromDateTime;
```

Comment: *From the edit of your question* You cannot order by something that is not being returned from the query. Group by date time and then you can order by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `top 3` means that you will return at most 3 rows *of your current result*. If you need to calculate averages on 3 rows, first you need to filter them. I would use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(ProcedureProjection),
    AVG(ProceduresPerformed),
    AVG(DPaCT.ProductProjection),
    AVG(DPaCT.ProductsCollected)
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 3 ProcedureProjection, ProceduresPerformed, DPaCT.ProductProjection, DPaCT.ProductsCollected
        FROM rpt_DriveMaster DM 
        INNER JOIN DriveProjectionandCollectedTotals DPaCT ON DM.DriveID = DPaCT.DriveID 
        INNER JOIN rpt_Accounts Acct ON DM.AccountID = Acct.AccountID
        where Acct.accountid='17845' and DM.fromdatetime < '2014-04-01' and DM.StatusID='2'
    ) as a
```